# How do I set up my own proxy server?

Tags: python, perl, proxy

This website (abc.com) slowed access from our original IP address. How do I implement my own proxy server to hide my IP while browsing abc.com? Do I need special hardware/software combo to achieve this?

If I can generate about 5 proxies and alternate amongst those 5 while browsing abc.com would be awesome. Please suggest. Thanks guys!

p.s : I want to know if I can generate proxy IPs of the type 123.34.21.140 prot 80 on my own? I want to use those IP/port combos in my Python scripts (urllib2/set_proxy).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying hide from them why don't you actually try and work up an agreement with the site so they actually allow your access.

If they chose to block you, then there may have been a legitimate reason.  Perhaps your requests far out-paced what their servers could handle.  Perhaps your requests where doing something wrong and causing problems on their network.  Perhaps your requests was using more bandwidth then what they considered to be reasonable.  If someone blocks you, it is very rare for the correct solution to be setting up proxies to distribute and hide your activities.

If you are overly abusive you also might quickly become the target of some kind of legal actions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't fake IP addresses (actually, you can, but it's useful in DDOS attacks etc), because when the other system tries to send back stuff to you, it won't find you there. You need to own the IP and setup or use a proxy server there.

Failing that, you can use an [open proxy](http://www.xroxy.com/proxylist.htm), or connect through an anonymity network ([Tor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_%28anonymity_network%29) is an example).